# Electric octupole in cartesian coordinates

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

I am new to this: Does anyone know to define different electric octupole moments in cartesian coordinates? I am looking for expressions that look like this (for electric dipoles).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given
\begin{align}
Y_1^{\pm 1}(\theta,\varphi)&= \pm C_{1} \left(\frac{x\pm iy}{r}\right)
\end{align}
why not start from the expression for the $\ell=3$ [spherical harmonics in Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics) and combine them to get real expressions, *v.g.*
\begin{align}
Y_3^3(\theta,\varphi)+ Y_3^{-3}(\theta,\phi)\sim (x-iy)^3+(x+iy)^3 = 2x^3-6 xy^2
\end{align}
and so forth?

An even more direct way is to start from [the real spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000021-QINU%60%22'%7F_=_3[2]) although that won't help you to have the Cartesian components in terms of the usual spherical harmonics.

Comment: Thanks @ZeroTheHero, in that case, how can we obtain "unique solutions" for x, y, and z?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean.  In general a polynomial like $z^3$ will expand in a sum of multipoles but the expansion is unique.